# ExtJS4 - Change font size of TabPanel title text

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs4, tabpanel

I need to change the text of the title of the tab in a `TabPanel`, but I don't want that this will affect every other `TabPanel` in the application, just this `TabPanel`.

I tried adding a CSS class by the `cls` property, by the `itemCls` property, and by this:

```
defaults: {
    cls: 'aClass'
}
```

The CSS:

```
.aClass {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

But they all look the same:

[image]

Nothing seemed to work. How am I able to achieve that?

Comment: Type an accurate font-size for it. And use <span class="aClass"> your text</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use the `cls` property on your tabpanel and then have a custom CSS selector that would only point to that tabpanel:

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/49Dc8/

**JS**

```
Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');

Ext.onReady(function(){
    // basic tabs 1, built from existing content
    var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs1',
        cls: 'mytab',
        width: 450,
        plain: true,
        activeTab: 0,
        defaults :{
            bodyPadding: 10
        },
        items: [{
            contentEl:'script', 
            title: 'Short Text'
        },{
            contentEl:'markup', 
            title: 'Long Text'
        }]
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.mytab .x-tab-inner{
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, Indeed I didn't find any reference to the `.x-tab-inner` selector. It worked, thanks!